# Wolfram format for mathmatics equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I am trying to solve a system of 4 equations in Wolfram.

x4 - x1 + x2 - x1 - b - b *x1 =0 , x1 -x2+x3-x2 - b- b* x2=0 , x1 -x4+x3-x4 + b - b* x4=0, x4 -x3+x2-x3 - b -b* x3=0 , b > 0, solve for{x1,x2,x3,x4}

but it keeps giving me error

Comment: `Solve[{x4 - x1 + x2 - x1 - b - b x1 == 0, 
  x1 - x2 + x3 - x2 - b - b x2 == 0, 
  x1 - x4 + x3 - x4 + b - b*x4 == 0, 
  x4 - x3 + x2 - x3 - b - b*x3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]`

Comment: Many Thanks it worked but how to add the condition b >0

Comment: That constraint does not change the solution provided. Mma provides a generic solution and trusts you to notice that `b` cannot equal `-2` or `-4`. If you want to see this explicitly, you can use `Reduce` instead of `Solve`. You can even `Simplify[
 Reduce[{x4 - x1 + x2 - x1 - b - b x1 == 0, 
   x1 - x2 + x3 - x2 - b - b x2 == 0, 
   x1 - x4 + x3 - x4 + b - b*x4 == 0, 
   x4 - x3 + x2 - x3 - b - b*x3 == 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4}], b > 0]`.